# Different timeouts in one URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

Is it possible to set different timeouts intervals per `URLRequest` using one `URLSession`?

I tried to set

`urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 20 * 60`

but it has been ignored by URLSession and request failed after default 60 sec with timeout error.

Only this setup change timeouts:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20 * 60 // 20 min
self.session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
```

but `20 * 60 // 20 min` is applied to all `URLRequest` in that session.

I want to allow some tasks to wait longer for response but rest of them should default failed after default 60 sec.

Is is possible? Or should I use more than one `URLSession`

PS. During research I found this bug:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2680

Comment: are you sure that it failed from ios side, not server side?

Comment: yes, when I set `timeoutIntervalForRequest` on `URLSessionConfiguration` then request waits more than 60 sec

Answer (score 1):

You can have configure the timeout for each individual URL. It's just that you can't set a timeout that is bigger than the URLSession's configuration itself.

> In some cases, the policies defined in this configuration may be
>   overridden by policies specified by an `NSURLRequest` object provided
>   for a task. Any policy specified on the request object is respected
>   **unless the session’s policy is more restrictive**. For example, if the
>   session configuration specifies that cellular networking should not be
>   allowed, the `NSURLRequest` object cannot request cellular networking.
>
> <sub>Docs on [URLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration)</sub>

The default timeout is 60 seconds. You're setting to 1200 which is bigger. So it doesn't work. Increase your configuration and then you can configure each url's timeout differently.

Answer (score -1):

Modifying a URLSession's properties after it has been assigned to a URLSession isn't supported, per Apple's documentation. You need to create the configuration separate and initialize a separate instance with it.

Comment: I am trying to modify `URLRequest` property. (`urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 20 * 60`) but it has no effect